# conditional IF to filter with multiple conditions by group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

so I have LARGE dataset but need to implement a complex system of filtering of the data. I think I could use dplyr and group_by but I am hitting a wall with how to get the IF statement implemented within the groups.

Here is what I tried and thought would have worked but I think there might be a problem with the indexing and thus getting multiple TRUE/FALSE per group. I am not sure how I would index though within each group.

For instance in the example below,
If the group GP contains the string "a", then keep any records that have Var4 equal to J or J1 (for that one I could do "that contains the letter "J"), but IF the group GP contains the string "b" and also has the string "2" (again here is it a simple number but in reality it would be a combo of string and number for everything), then keep records where Var4 if "J", but if the group GP contains the string "b" and also has the string "3" then keep records where Var4 if "U"... here there are cases in this example, but ultimately I was giving rules that I need to apply and I would have 300+ of those "IF the group has these qualities, then keep those records".

```
testing <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "a", "b", "b","a", "a","b", "b"),
                      var2 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3),
                      var3 = c("A", "A", "A", "A","B", "B","B", "B"),
                      var4 = c("U", "J", "J", "A", "1", "J1", "U", "A"))
testing$GP <- paste(testing$var1,testing$var2, testing$var3, sep = "-")
cleaned <- testing %>% 
  group_by("GP") %>% 
  if (grepl("a", testing$GP)){
    filter(testing, testing$var4 == "J" | testing, testing$var4 == "J1")
  } else if  (grepl("b", testing$GP) & grepl("2", testing$GP)){
    filter(testing, testing$var4 == "J")
  } else if  (grepl("b", testing$GP) & grepl("3", testing$GP)){
    filter(testing, testing$var4 == "U")
  }
```

Ultimately I would like a result equivalent as below, but with 100000 records and being able to build the 300 conditions I need ("Joy" ;-P)

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4    GP
1    a    1    A    U a-1-A
3    b    2    A    J b-2-A
6    a    1    B   J1 a-1-B
7    b    3    B    U b-3-B
```

What I need it to be able to conditionally filter out an insane amount of data based on conditions applied to three variables. For instance, I need, for each separate unique group of three variables (e.g. b-3-B if looking a the last group), to keep the record(s) that would fit a result (e.g. "U") but only if some condition is met (e.g. "GP" contains the string "b", and the string "3"). But I have to do this for 300 different groups that have sometimes complex IF statements (e.g. for the GP, keep records with result "U" in the 4th variables if the "GP" contains certain string "EG", but if it has the string "RT" then keep records that are "J" in the 4th variables...

thank you.
Sab

Comment: Good job on your first post. I'd suggest describing your conditions separately outside of the code so that people don't have to guess what you need. Your attempt could be very different from what you actually need and lead people in the wrong direction.

Comment: Can you describe in words what your are trying to do? Also `testing$wierdID` is missing.

Comment: @markus, thank you, I have updated the code. It was what my "GP" variable was called in the original dataset.

Comment: @Shree what I need it to be able to conditionally filter out an insane amount of data based on conditions applied to three variables. For instance, I need, for each separate unique group of three variables (e.g. b-3-B) to keep the record(s) that would fit a result (e.g. "U") but only if some condition is met (e.g. "GP" contains the string "b", and the string "3")

Comment: @SabP Just list out your conditions in your original post. You'll get help faster that way. If too many, then list out a few at least and describe the pattern if any.

Comment: @Shree is this what you mean?

Comment: Are your conditions listed in some table that can be looked up? Or is there any pattern to the conditions?

Comment: @Shree the conditions were given to me literally as stated above "IF var1 == "X1", and for the unique combo of var1-var2-var3, you have the choices for var4 are Z1 or Z2, then only keep the record with Z2, but if the choices are Z1 and Z3 then keep the record with Z3" and if changes for about 290 different value of X and some minute variations of var1:var3. I wish I had a look up table... I could potentially put one together of the form Var1, IF1: var4 == cond1, IF2: var4 == cond2, Choose...but it is were I am wondering how to get each group of unique var1:3 to go through that table

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping that you could combine certain conditions and reduce some redundant typing.

For the given example, we could use combination of `grepl` statements with `&` and `|` operators to include various combination of conditions. Hopefully, you'll be able to extend this further based on your requirement.

```
library(dplyr)

testing %>%
  filter(grepl("a", GP) & grepl("J|J1", var4) | 
         grepl("b", GP) & grepl("2", GP) & grepl("J", var4) |
         grepl("b", GP) & grepl("3", GP) & grepl("U", var4))


#  var1   var2 var3  var4  GP   
# <fct>  <dbl> <fct> <fct> <chr>
#1 a         1 A     J     a-1-A
#2 b         2 A     J     b-2-A
#3 a         1 B     J1    a-1-B
#4 b         3 B     U     b-3-B
```

Or directly subset in base R using the same conditions

```
testing[with(testing,grepl("a", GP) & grepl("J|J1", var4) | 
                     grepl("b", GP) & grepl("2", GP) & grepl("J", var4) |
                     grepl("b", GP) & grepl("3", GP) & grepl("U", var4)), ]
```

Comment: Thank you, but the conditions changes depending on the sets of unique combinations of the first three variables; hence my trying to get this to apply to the group_by

Comment: @SabP but if your conditions follow the same pattern can you add them one below the other as shown for 3 of them in the example? Ultimately you need to filter the rows irrespective of the groups, right? Atleast groups don't play any role in the example shown.

Comment: thank you. I will need to reinspect the conditions given to me; as they were given to me based on the groups such as if in each group of Var1:3, if Var1 == X1, and the possibilities listed for Var4 are Z1 or Z2, then keep Z2, but if they are Z1 or Z3, then keep Z1. My guess is that the conditions would change based on the Var1-var3 combos since they were given to me as such.

Comment: I verified, and it does depend of the options/choice of var4 per each group. For most groups, the simplified code above you provided would have worked as it is always the same combo of choices in var4 for a specific var1, but not always. For instance, in my example above, here a form of J option is chosen, but if something "better" than J is present for that combo of var1:3 then I should grab that one and not J.